# How to set up bridge network connection for Fedora 30 to work with libvirt KVM

Tags: linux, networking, fedora, home-networking

To work with KVM VM's in Fedora 30 I need to set up bridge connection. So I managed to write some simple script, but seems i have some issue. If i am correct, then properties i entered for bridge connection are not passed to Ethernet connection when i add bridge-slave  connection? Could you please give me a hint on my issue in this script file?
This is my `./bridge.sh` script:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Author: Dzintars Klavins
# This script will setup bridge connection to enable KVM networking
# Before runing, delete all devices and connections
# nmcli connection delete <connection-name>
# nmcli device delete <device-name>
# Don't forget to make this file executable

export NETWORK_ETHERNET_DEVICE="eno1"
export NETWORK_ETHERNET_CONNECTION="eno1"
export NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION="br1"
export NETWORK_GW_ADDRESS="192.168.1.1"
export NETWORK_IP_ADDRESS="192.168.1.2"
export NETWORK_DNS_ADDRESES="8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4"

# General cleanup

# Delete all existing connections
for i in `nmcli c | \
grep -o -- "[0-9a-fA-F]\{8\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{12\}"` ; \
do nmcli connection delete uuid $i ; \
done

# Delete all devices (optional/not sure)
for i in `nmcli d | \
grep -o -- "[0-9a-fA-F]\{8\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{4\}-[0-9a-fA-F]\{12\}"` ; \
do nmcli device delete uuid $i ; \
done

# Create new bridge connection
nmcli connection add type bridge autoconnect yes con-name ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION} ifname ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION}
# Modify bridge connection properties
nmcli connection modify ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION} ipv4.address ${NETWORK_IP_ADDRESS}/24
nmcli connection modify ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION} ipv4.method manual
nmcli connection modify ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION} ipv4.gateway ${NETWORK_GW_ADDRESS}
nmcli connection modify ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION} ipv4.dns ${NETWORK_DNS_ADDRESES}
# Bring bridged connection up
nmcli connection up ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION}
# Add slave for bridged connection
nmcli connection add type bridge-slave autoconnect yes con-name ${NETWORK_ETHERNET_CONNECTION} ifname ${NETWORK_ETHERNET_DEVICE} master ${NETWORK_BRIDGE_CONNECTION}
# Bring up slave connection
nmcli connection down ${NETWORK_ETHERNET_CONNECTION}; nmcli connection up ${NETWORK_ETHERNET_CONNECTION}

ping google.com
# ... no ping :( :( :(
```

It kinda works, but it doesn't ping google. I see 2 devices created:

```
$ nmcli device
DEVICE      TYPE      STATE        CONNECTION 
br1         bridge    connected    br1        
eno1        ethernet  connected    eno1       
wlp6s0u1    wifi      unavailable  --         
lo          loopback  unmanaged    --         
virbr0-nic  tun       unmanaged    --
```

And 2 connections as well:

```
$ nmcli connection
NAME  UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE 
br1   7ed7ca67-8a92-4ba4-a526-092efbf6c4ea  bridge    br1    
eno1  00b1f26a-c83e-46eb-a432-aa749f798d08  ethernet  eno1
```

Output of `ip addr`:

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:96:49:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
8: wlp6s0u1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7e:fd:21:9f:4f:03 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
50: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:b6:5f:4f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
73: br1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 30:85:a9:96:49:ef brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.2/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global noprefixroute br1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::b71a:aa17:83b:f53/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: UPD. IIRC this script worked. The issue was that I just need to wait a little bit 20-60 secs and then Ping works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I assume your ping from kvm client s not getting through the bridge, but ping at host is ok.

I have the same problem setting up bridging for kvm. I listed the iptables rules and noticed firewalld setup (Fedora 30/31) is missing final ACCEPT of forward chain in default zone bridge interface. The final ACCEPTs are in FWDI_libvirt and FWDO_libvirt tables.

So, either change default zone for your bridge interface to libvirt and enable services in libvirt, or append the forward rules for your default zone. Assuming your bridge interface br0 or br1 default zone is "public", do this (change public to whatever zone necessary):

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-passthrough ipv4 -A FWDI_public -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-passthrough ipv4 -A FWDO_public -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

These direct iptables rules will be added in /etc/firewalld/direct.xml

Another way is to forward all incoming and outgoing packets for br0 or br1

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --permanent --direct --add-passthrough ipv4 -A FORWARD -o br0 -j ACCEPT
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: omg you just saved my butt. I was having issues getting the libvirtio interface to connect with my machines and nothing was working. thank you so much!